# send data back to the parent from child via both back button and up/home action menu

Tags: android

I want to send back data to Parent activity. My code works only when back button is pressed. When i navigate back to parent using home/up menu, it does not send back the intent or result.

here is the sendBack method in (ChildActivity):
this method will be invoked within a button.setOnClickListener

```
public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "answer_is_correct";
.
.
.
private void sendBackResult(boolean isCorrect) {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, isCorrect);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

here is a snippet of the Parent code (mainActivity):

```
//isCorrect is used later to check data sent from child and take any action e.g display a Toast
boolean isCorrect;
.
.
//overridden method
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (data == null){
        return;
    }
    isCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE,false);
}
```

when i press back button at  the bottom of my phone it sends back my data perfectly, but if i use the action bar Up/Home option it does not work. i have tried using the following within onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

```
int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        sendBackResult(isCorrect);
    }
```

it still wont work. any suggestions, btw ParentActivity is set in Manifest. Navigation is working, it just wont send back data or intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the up button having the same functionality as the physical back button, you could use:

```
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.home) {
    sendBackResult(isCorrect);
    finish();
}
```

If you do choose to use this, you will no longer need to specify the parent activity within the manifest

Comment: thanks, but i have tried that already to no avail, setResult(RESULT_OK, data) will only send back the intent when i press back button. Up is not sending back the intent.

Comment: You tried using `finish();` instead of `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);`?